# manage jquery tables with watin

Tags: watin, specflow

I am using Watin with Cucumber and Specflow to automate the testing of a web application using a jquery table.
I want to find a specific data in the table, but i don't know how to access the table. When I find the data i am looking for, i want to return the id of the row to pass it to an URL that navigate to the Delete page so I can delete the data.
This is my code in the page:

```
<tr id="S-1-5-21-373314506-2757628719-1954316189-3686" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row" tabindex="-1">
<td class="ui-state-default jqgrid-rownum" aria-describedby="list_rn" title="2" style="text-align:center;" role="gridcell">2</td>
<td aria-describedby="list_Actions" title="Edit | Details | Delete" style="" role="gridcell">
<a href="/Budget.Administrator/User/Edit?id=S-1-5-21-373314506-2757628719-1954316189-3686">Edit</a>
```

|
    [Details](/Budget.Administrator/User/Details?id=S-1-5-21-373314506-2757628719-1954316189-3686)
|
[Delete](/Budget.Administrator/User/Delete?id=S-1-5-21-373314506-2757628719-1954316189-3686)

Ivana Bagur

So, in this example, I want to go through my table and when i find Ivana Bagur, return the tr id attribute so then I can pass this id attribute to effectively delete the element.
Can anyone give me an idea how to go through the table until i find the data and then capture the tr id?

Answer (score 0):

First, something is off in the code you posted as it is not showing entirely correctly; somehow you got actual links to display starting at 'details' rather than your code.

To find the TR ID....general idea:

1. Find the element containing Ivana Bagur
2. Find the ancestor of that element that is a TR.

If Ivana is just text in a tablcell it might look like:

```
string IvanaRowID = ((TableRow)(myIE.Table(myID).tablecell(Find.ByText(myRegexContainingIvanaBagur)).Ancestor("tr"))).Id;
```

It has been a while since I've done this, and my casting might be a bit off / non-optimal, but the general idea is there.